# Tools : Google Cloud Tools menu option is not available in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

In the following video :

http://youtu.be/7Sp4Lr3Qmcw?t=16m6s

at 16:06 into the video, the presenter uses the Tools -> Google Cloud Tools -> Install Client Libraries menu option in Android Studio. However, this menu option does not seem to be present in v1.0.2 of Android Studio

[image]

Comment: Did you just try adding the dependency from the client project? As in `compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')`?

Comment: Yes. I have the dependency   compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints') in my app/build.gradle but it still does not generate the client libraries corresponding to the new api

Comment: Are you getting any Gradle errors? Or just not doing anything without any error message?

Comment: Not getting any gradle errors when I make module or rebuild project. Gradle builds without any errors but when I try to use the backend CheckInEndpoint class in my app, and try to build, it gives me the following error : Error:(66, 22) error: package CheckInEndpoint does not exist. I am using the sample code from here : https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/#saeba

Answer (score 1):

The cloud tools feature integration in Android Studio has changed somewhat since that video was made.  You shouldn't need to run 'Install Client Libraries' anymore.  The dependency between the Android App and the cloud module is managed automatically and simply building the module or doing a Gradle sync should allow you to use the client libraries from the Android app.
(Assuming you used the new module wizard to create your cloud modules)

For the most up to date documentation look [here](https://cloud.google.com/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

> appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs - Install generated client libs
>   into the local Maven repository

You can run this directly from the terminal

```
gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs
```

In short just type:

```
gradlew aEICL
```

If you want more information about available tasks try:

```
gradlew <module-name>:tasks
```